# how to create cart content as pdf output in PRESTASHOP

Tags: prestashop

I have to print the cart content in a pdf file and download.

I have try some code using pdfinvoicecontroller.php

1. I have created new controller - controllers/front/CartprintController.php

   class CartprintControllerCore extends FrontController
       {
       protected $display_header = false;
       protected $display_footer = false;

   ```
       public $content_only = true;

   protected $template;
   public $filename; 

   public function postProcess()
   { 
   if (!$this->context->customer->isLogged() && !Tools::getValue('secure_key'))
   Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=authentication&back=cartprint'); 
   } 

   public function display()
   {   
         $displayproducts = $this->context->cart->getProducts();   

   $pdf = new PDF($displayproducts, PDF::TEMPLATE_INVOICE_CART, $this->context->smarty, $this->context->language->id);

   $pdf->render(); 
   } 
   public function getTemplate()
   { 
   $template = _PS_THEME_PDF_DIR_.'/cartprint.tpl'; 

   return $template;
   } 
   }
   ```
2. Added

   const TEMPLATE_INVOICE_CART = 'Cartprint';

line in classes/pdf/PDF.php

3.then created a HTML template file in pdf/cartprint.tpl

```
<table id="cart_summary" class="std">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="cart_product first_item">{l s='Product'}</th>
<th class="cart_description item">{l s='Description'}</th>

<th class="cart_unit item">{l s='Unit price'}</th>
<th class="cart_quantity item">{l s='Qty'}</th>
<th class="cart_total item">{l s='Total'}</th>

</tr>
</thead>
{foreach  $displayproducts  item=prodpef name=prodpef }
<tr>
<td class="cart_product first_item">{$prodpef.name}</td>
<td class="cart_description item">{$prodpef.description_short}</td>

<td class="cart_unit item">{$prodpef.price}</td>>
<td class="cart_quantity item">{$prodpef.cart_quantity}</td>>
<td class="cart_total item">{$prodpef.total}</td>> 

</tr>
{/foreach}

</table>
```

4.in shopping cart page i have created a link

```
<a href="{$link->getPageLink('cartprint', true, NULL)}" title="{l s='Invoice'}" class="_blank"><img src="{$img_dir}icon/pdf.gif" alt="{l s='Invoice'}" class="icon" /></a>
```

but still i am not getting pdf output .

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

First it will be better to override PDF class and second you need to create a HTMLTemplateCartPrint.php file in classes dir or override classes dir in order to generate pdf file.

Best regards.

Comment: If you can provide an answer with some code and guidance, that will help many people :)